# Can Dolphin File Manager be downloaded for Windows?

Tags: windows, files, downloads, dolphin

I was on the Dolphin website, but there didn't seem to be a download or purchase button anywhere. Is Dolphin available for Windows? If so, could someone please link me to a page to download or purchase the latest version?

Comment: This is off-topic here, as this site is only about Ubuntu.

Comment: KDE can be installed on Windows, including Dolphin: [KDE on Windows](http://techbase.kde.org/Projects/KDE_on_Windows/Installation).

Answer (score 3):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolphin_%28file_manager%29
Wikipedia states, that the Dolphin FM is avabible for windows, but I cant see a download link on their webpage. I think it is like that because it is made for KDE. Try this link: http://alternativeto.net/software/dolphin/?platform=windows